# Why my app is not compatible with old OS versions like 4.4 etc?

Tags: android, android-studio

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

in above code, i have given my apps dependencies. i want to know whether dependencies

Comment: Why don't you just try building to that earlier target and then see what the error messages say?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen earlier target means targetsdkversion ? It's 26 for my apk.what should I do ?